# How to load a partial using Ajax in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a partial to load when a search is detected. It may take a very long time to load in some cases, so I would like it to load via Ajax once the page is fully loaded otherwise it will most likely cause a timeout.

The way I am doing it currently is resulting in a synchronously load.

I would also like a loading screen to be shown, until it's fully loaded. This is working currently but only with the timeout set, as its a synchronous load.

```
    <% if(params[:q][:name_cont].present?) %>

  <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

      function load_partial() {     
        $("div.super_search").replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'super_search_tp') %>');
                                          }

                                          // use setTimeout() to execute
                                          setTimeout(load_partial, 1000)

      });

  </script>

  <div class="super_search">

    <i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Loading Product Analysis...

  </div>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method for the partial in the controller:

```
  def super_search
    @search = @@products
    render :layout => false
  end
```

Rename the partial so it was the view for this method.

Add in the `@@products` to the index method so that the data from the search can be used in the new method:

```
@@top_products = @q.result
```

Code to render the partial:

```
<% if(params[:q][:name_cont].present?) %>

      <script>

        $.ajax({
          url: "/products/super_search",
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
            $("#foo-bar").replaceWith(html);
          }
        });

      </script>

      <div class="super_search" id="foo-bar">

        <i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Loading Product Analysis...

      </div>

        <% end %>
```